# Why isn't this finite set $A = \vert\{x | \space 2<x<3, x \in \mathbb{R} \}\vert$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

$$A = \vert\{x | \space 2<x<3, x \in \mathbb{R} \}\vert $$

Why isn't this finite set?

Comment: If it's finite, write down the elements. If I find one that you did not write, I win.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli lmao

Comment: I am not completely joking. You ought to back up your claims, oughtn't you?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I've math exam tomorrow. Honestly, I'm so excited rofl

Comment: Why do you think it is finite ? Find me the smallest element in that interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is infinite because in contains the numbers $2+\frac12$, $2+\frac13$, $2+\frac14$, …

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks =;)

Comment: @Maxime I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are working within an interval of the real numbers, which is an *uncountable* set. Try reading about Cantor's diagonal argument to see why.

Comment: The question did not ask for a proof of the existence of infinite sets. By using Cantor's method we know there is an infinite amount of points within any interval in real numbers, hence an infinite set. However, you are right in saying Cantor assumed their existence.

Comment: Thinking about it, the theorem kinda does prove that $(0,1)$ is infinite. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being 'mislead' by the fact the 'distance' between 2 and 3 is finite. That is, you have a finite interval here ... how come there are infinitely many things on that finite interval?  Well, one way to see this is to pick any number between 2 and 3, and once you have done that, pick a number between 2 and that number and then between 2 and *that* number, etc. etc.  I think you can see that you can keep doing this indefinitely, so that gives you infinitely many points right there.